Using Apache Nifi with Plc4xSourceProcessor to read modbus data
I'm using Apache Nifi 1.22.0 and Plc4xSourceProcessor 0.12.0 to read ModBus data.
Connection string: modbus-tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:port seems to work fine.
I'm trying to read from 30001 (Read Input registers), but no matter what json I provide to AddressText it does not generate a flow file with data.
How can I read 10 data fields starting from 0 on Read input registers using Plc4xSourceProcessor? (Address text is asking for a json) When I use Modbus Poll tool, I receive data in both ASCII and RTU modes.
I tried many combinations of JSON for AddressText, Can someone please tell me the exact JSON to read 30001, I spent nearly 4 days on this as there is a lack of examples.

Managed to figure out.
Connection string should be (for 0.12.0 other versions have other formats)
modbus-tcp:tcp://xxx.xx.xx.xx:port
Address Text --> Here I'm fetching 10 rows from the input register. It could be 40001 for holding register. Row 0 is 1.
{"row0":30001,"row1":30002,"row2":30003,"row3":30004,"row4":30005,"row5":30006,"row6":30007,"row7":30008,"row8":30009,"row9":30010}
Most important point is that the values would be returned as attributes (not a flow file etc). So don't panic if return bytes is 0. Use AttributesToJSON to capture all rows into a JSON

It's okay to answer your own question. It may help others with a similar problem.

Hi, yes we are trying to streamline all of our drivers to work the same way ... some times we need to update some of the formats for that. We hope to arrive at version 1.0.0 some time soon from where on you can expect a lot more stable format.

Thank you @ChristoferDutz, Its good to know someone who is deeply knowledgeable about the topic as we're working with some devices communicating through Modbus. Thank you once again!
